# secure message transmission with asymmetric keys

Tags: x509certificate, encryption-asymmetric

I need to securely transmit a short message in a non-secure channel, so that a MITM cannot read it and cannot replay it.

The message must be transmitted by entity A to entity B. B has an X509 certificate (PubKey, PrivKey) and A can check PubKey.

Here is a simple 3-step cinematic I have in mind, but I fear it is naive and could be easily broken :

```
A                            B
|          random x          |
| -------------------------> |
|                            |
|   PubKey, f1(PrivKey, x)   |
| <------------------------- |
|                            |
|       f2(PubKey, msg)      |
| -------------------------> |
```

(f1 and f2 are encryption functions)

What are the risks, and how to improve it ?

Comment: Is it a homework? If so, it should be mentioned in your question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to Information Security site.

Comment: It is not homework, but it is neither intended to be implemented as is. This is just a general question about the best way to transmit a short message : indeed, a SSL handshake seems to be a bit complicated for that simple need.
If there already exists such reliable protocols, please let me know.